# Cannot find url_encoded_fmt_stream_map in youtube content

Tags: php, youtube

Hey i'm creating a youtube downloader website and i need this "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map" in my php code but it seems like this key gone from the youtube contents. Can someone help me about this problem? Thanks.

This is my code(PHP) :

```
    $data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=$id_video ");


    parse_str($data,$arr);

$urls =explode(",",$arr['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map']);
```

Comment: Could you try to format your code into a code block?

Comment: @zehata done,sorry for that